# MERN & Redux: How do you pass Redux state data from Index to Show page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, mern

--SHORT VERSION
My Index page is a list of all Tournaments.  Each has a button you click to go to that tournament's page.
In Index on each tournament I have a button that has `onClick={}` the action that selects that Tournaments data in the Redux.

How do I access that state data properly on the next page?

--LONG VERSION
I have a Tournament model with a bunch of express routes written in the backend for the full CRUD.

I also have redux written out.. I got the Index page (list of all tournaments in the DB)
I'm gonna show my `GET ALL TOURNAMENTS` code, so you can see how I transitioned into creating the `SHOW ONE TOURNAMENT` code.

**BackEnd ExpressJS route**

```
// @route       GET /tournaments
// @descrip Get All, INDEX
// @access  Public
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Tournament.find()
        .sort({ date: -1 })
        .then(tournaments => res.json(tournaments))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    tournaments: [],
    loading: false
}
```

```
case GET_TOURNAMENTS:
    return {
        ...state,
        tournaments: action.payload,
        loading: false
    };
```

**Action**

```
export const getTournaments = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setTourneysLoading()); 
    axios
        .get('/tournaments')
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: GET_TOURNAMENTS,
            payload: res.data
        }))
        .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};
```

All right.. thanks for your patience!  Here's what I have for SHOW

**Express Route**

```
// @route   SHOW /tournaments/:id
// @descrip Display a single tournament
// @access  Public
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Tournament.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(tournament => res.json(tournament))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ msg: "Tournament not found" }));
});
```

**Reducer**

```
case DISPLAY_TOURNAMENT:
    return {
        ...state,
        // Iterate through tournaments to find one that matches payload
        tournaments: state.tournaments.map(tournament => tournament._id === action.payload ?
            // display that tournament
            { tournament } :
            // else, display nothing
            null
        ),
        loading: false
    };
```

**Action**

```
export const showTournament = id => dispatch => {
    dispatch(singleTourneyLoading());   
    axios
        .get(`/tournaments/${id}`)
        .then(() => dispatch({
            type: DISPLAY_TOURNAMENT,
            payload: id
        }))
        .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};
```

Do I simply need to create a new reducer for this alone? 
I can see the displayed tournament in the State.  On the frontEnd i'm trying to pull that from State so I can render the data using PropTypes.

I didn't wanna make this a huge post but I'll put my Show file here so everything is out in the open

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TournamentDescription from './descriptions';
import { showTournament } from '../../actions/tournamentActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class TournamentShow extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.showTournament(this.props.tournament._id);
    };
    static propTypes = {
        showTournament: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        tournament: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };
    render() {
        const { _id, title, hostedBy, status, participants } = this.props.tournament;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{ title }</h1>
                <h3> <TournamentDescription key={_id} title={ title } /> </h3>
                <p>status: { status }</p>
                <p>Registered Fighters:
                    {
                        participants.map((participant, index) => {
                            return (
                                <ul key={ index }>
                                    <li>{ participant }</li>
                                </ul>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </p>
                <p>Hosted by: { hostedBy }</p>
                <Link to="#">Sign Up</Link>
                <Link to="/">Back to Tournaments main page</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    tournament: state.tournament.tournaments[0],
    auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { showTournament })(TournamentShow);
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `tournament` data in the state, you can get this data directly using the 
 `this.props`, and also using the `componentDidUpdate` function in `TournamentShow` class. You can verify if the value has been updated, in the next example I'm using the equals library to compare the value of tournament property:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(!equal(this.props.tournament, prevProps.tournament)) {
      //Some operations with tournament value
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm going to try this now.
Does it make sense that I have the Reducer action for grabbing the Show Tournament(id) in the AllTournaments component?

Do I need that ShowTournament Action in both components?

Comment: My guess is `ShowTournament` only should be call in one component (TournamentShow), if the `ShowTournament` is call in both components the response it will be the same but an unnecessary request it will be performed. In other hand, you can use `find` instead of `map` on reducer: `state.tournaments.find(tournament =>tournament._id === action.payload ? {tournament}: null` that returns a single result.

Comment: Ah, that was a great tip.  That returns the proper tournament I select in the data.
I'm getting `Cannot read property of undefined` when I click the button that activates showTournament().  Seems something isn't getting passed through correctly.. 

I'm pretty sure I"m way off somehow